# ¿mysql_free_result($resultado) en insert?

Tags: php

tengo una consulta en relación a `mysql_free_result($resultado)`.

Según he visto en el api de PHP, sirve para liberar la memoria después de una consulta... No sé si es correcto usarlo después de cada consulta, o solo para los Select. En el caso que pregunto, ¿es correcto usarlo después de un insert?

Gracias.

Comment: Si la sentencia no es SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN, no hay resultset a liberar.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar te diré que [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.free.php) es clara: `mysql_free_result()`fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0. En su lugar debería utilizarse `mysqli_free_result()` para procedimientos y `mysqli_result::free_result()` para objetos.

Luego dice tambien que debe usarse con un conjunto de identificadores de resultados devuelto por `mysqli_query()`, `mysqli_store_result()` o `mysqli_use_result()` y no menciona nada más.

Considera también leer [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502201/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-mysql-free-resultresult) para que resuelvas más dudas.